# How to upload files in Google Drive v3 without opening a browser window?

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3, file-upload

I've got the following problem with my application:
I want to upload simple files to google drive, get no error, but it doesn't seem to work, because no file is being uploaded.
I've enabled the API at google, added

```
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
```

to my project, but I can't get out why it won't work.
I've tried different solutions provided by google, but none of them is working. 
To get the required information, I use

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net; 
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json
    static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };
    static string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true), new LocalServerCodeReceiver()).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Drive API service.
       // new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.DriveService()
        var service = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });
        // Define parameters of request.
        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
       // listRequest.PageSize = 10;
        listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

        //Upload File
        gUpload(service, @"C:\Users\xxx\test.txt"); //THIS DOES NOT WORK

        // List files.
        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute().Files;
        Console.WriteLine("Files:");
        if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file in files)
            { //THIS WORKS FINE
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.OriginalFilename, file.Id);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This will give me the correct credentials and lists all Files contained in my gDrive folders as well as its trash-files.

The other way, add files instead of list them does not work anyway:

```
    public static void TestUpload(string filePath, DriveService driveService)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath.ToString()))
        {
            File body = new File();
            body.Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath.ToString());
            body.Description = "Test Description";
            body.MimeType = "text/plain";
            byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
            FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request = driveService.Files.Create(body, stream, "text/plain");
            request.Upload();
            File file = request.ResponseBody; //returns null value
        }

    }
```

This runs without any error, but the request is null and there is nothing uploaded, one of my other trys runs as well without errors, but does not upload anything.

```
public static bool gUpload(Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService service, string filePath)
    {

        string fileID = "0B-W1aRTTOB1QM3hPd0dOUFVObHM"; //random
        System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        File fBody = new File { Name = "test.txt" };

        var r = service.Files.Update(fBody, fileID, stream, "application/octet-stream");
        r.ChunkSize = ResumableUpload.MinimumChunkSize;
        r.Resume();
        // UploadStatus.Completed
        return true;
    }
```

I hope there is anyone out there to give me a working answer on how to change the code to get the upload working.

Best Regards
Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using wrong scopes, it should be `DriveService.Scope.Drive` (but it might be excess). Also don't forget to remove cached credentials from as soon as you update scopes list. You can check scopes [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth).